# Vimperator: The annoying keyboard shortcut in non-normal mode

Tags: firefox, vimperator

When I'm in non-normal mode (insert, command mode, etc.), the keyboard shortcut binding will change to the native one in firefox. (ctrl+n for opening new window instead of switching to the next tab)

Any way to solve this problem?

P.S. My firefox has a version of 10.0.1